# Exception before Main

Tags: c#, exception

I created app with following code (just for research purposes):

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Permissions;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    public class Program
    {
        static Program()
        {
            throw new Exception("Here we are");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
        }
    }
}
```

I expect that I would have a `TypeInitializationException` exception here before calling the `Main()` method because a static ctor must be called only once and just before first calling of any member of this class. 
So, in this case, CLR has to call static ctor for the Program class and after that it has to call the `Main()` method.
But here is one strange thing: this exception is thrown from the `Main()`. But why? We should have the exception from another place because Main can't be invoked.

Here is exception message:

> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'HelloWorld.Program' threw an exception. ---> System.Exception: Here we are
>          at HelloWorld.Program..cctor() in D:\research\HelloWorld\Program.cs:line 13
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          **at HelloWorld.Program.Main(String[] args)**

**Update:**

I have this message.

[image]

Unfortunately I can't debug app after this exception.

Comment: Just a guess, but I think it only calls the constructor when needed. The first time the class is required is when invoking Main, so I think that's the trigger for the constructor call, and maybe that's why it says the exception was raised on Main.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the full source code of your Program.cs file? Your code block has only 12 lines, but the error message mention line 13. Do not edit the error message or stack trace.

Comment: interesting message if you try to debug after exception is thrown. `Your app has entered a break state, but no code is currently executing that is supported by the selected debug engine (e.g. only native runtime code is executing)`

Comment: @Progman line number is the actual line number in cs file. so if you put 100 empty lines and throw exception at line 100 it will be line 100. its not important here.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary, in the constructor before throwing this exception I see just my ctor and [ExternalCode] in the call stack.

But if I define another class with static ctor I see call stack like that:

3. static ctor();
2.[External Code];
1. Main().

CLR has internal mechanism to call static ctor, but I don't know why it sets Main() as head of call stack when Main() actually has not executed yet.

Comment: Because: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ze4ytsc.aspx "The main function serves as the starting point for program execution."

Comment: The top line of the trace is correctly pointing to the static ctor at line 13. And that was called from (or caused by) Main(). Nothing wrong here.

Comment: Dump the .NET assembly for this program and read over it carefully.  I _suspect_ that `Main` is calling some internal routine to execute static constructors as its first operation.  I don't know this for certain, but that was once a common way to invoke static constructors in C++, before there were special ELF sections to handle them instead.

Comment: main is the One :-) One https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zYwdzYC3uUc

Comment: My understanding is that Main is the entry point to the assembly (the executable in this case) and that is invoked by the OS. Probably they do some hidden initialization (say initialize the .NET runtime etc.) at the very start of main, before the body of main executes

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's not specific to `Main` entry point method. Consider this code:

```
public class Program
{        
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        MyClass.Test();
    }
}

static class MyClass {
    static MyClass() {            
        throw new Exception("here we are");
    }

    public static void Test() {
        Console.WriteLine("test");
    }
}
```

If you run it, exception stack trace will be:

> Unhandled exception: System.TypeInitializationException: Type
>   initialized for "ConsoleApp2.MyClass" threw an exception. --->
>   System.Exception: here we are
>
> at ConsoleApp2.MyClass..cctor()
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> **at ConsoleApp2.MyClass.Test()**
>
> at ConsoleApp2.Program.Main(String[] args)

So, the same situation as with exception in static constructor of entry point class.

If you run that application with WinDbg and run `!clrstack` when exception is thrown, you will see:

> 000000af568fdc98 00007ffd54659d98 [GCFrame: 000000af568fdc98]
>
> 000000af568fde58 00007ffd54659d98 [GCFrame: 000000af568fde58]
>
> 000000af568fea00 00007ffd54659d98 [**PrestubMethodFrame**:
>   000000af568fea00] **ConsoleApp2.MyClass.Test()**
>
> 000000af568febe0 00007ffce37704a2
>   ConsoleApp2.Program.Main(System.String[])
>
> 000000af568fee40 00007ffd42d86793 [GCFrame: 000000af568fee40]

And in stack window you can see:

> clr!MethodTable::DoRunClassInitThrowing + 0x599
>
> clr!MethodTable::CheckRunClassInitThrowing + 0xbb
>
> clr!MethodDesc::DoPrestub + 0xd1d

When exactly to call static type constructor is determined by JIT compiler. When type explicitly defines static constructor, C# compiler will not mark type with [BeforeFieldInit](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx) flag. Types with that flags are allowed to be initialized
in "relaxed" fashion, at some point before their members are accessed (or at least before their static fields are accessed). So for them, JIT might emit static constructor call at any point before you access them, even right on startup of your application. Types without that flag are initialized in "precise" fashion - JIT will emit call to static constructor for them right when some member is accessed for the first time.

JIT performs compilation of methods on the fly. If method is not yet compiled into native code - method will point to a "stub". This stub contains code to run JIT, inspect method, compile it into native code, and then change method pointer from stub to compiled native code, so that on next call to this method flow goes directly to compiled code, without stub.

As you can see from WinDbg output - when exception happens, we are in a stub of  `MyClass.Test()` method.  At this point, when performing compilation of `MyClass.Test()` into native code, JIT sees that static constructor has not been run, emits code to call static constructor and compiles `MyClass.Test()`. But all this happens *after* method is technically called (but before any code from that method has actually been executed), so it appears on call stack.

I've used different code to illustrate it's not related to `Main`, but situation with code from your question is the same:

> 0000007ba0b3dba8 00007ffbfbb89d98 [GCFrame: 0000007ba0b3dba8]
>
> 0000007ba0b3dd68 00007ffbfbb89d98 [GCFrame: 0000007ba0b3dd68]
>
> 0000007ba0b3e910 00007ffbfbb89d98 [**PrestubMethodFrame**:
>   0000007ba0b3e910] **ConsoleApp2.Program.Main**(System.String[])
>
> 0000007ba0b3ed20 00007ffbfbb89d98 [GCFrame: 0000007ba0b3ed20]

Answer (score 8):

I executed code where, Test class is having static constructor which throws error,

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Test");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            try
            {
                Test t = new Test();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                       Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }

class Test
    {
        static Test()
        {
            throw new Exception("Errror");
        }        
    }
```

After it get executed it gives following output

```
Test
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Test.Test' threw a
n exception. ---> System.Exception: Errror
   at Test.Test..cctor() in \\gbl.ad.hedani.net\home_ap$\prana3$\Documents\Visua
l Studio 2015\Projects\Test\Test\Program.cs:line 45
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Test.Test..ctor()
   at Test.Program.Main(String[] args) in \\gbl.ad.hedani.net\home_ap$\prana3$\D
ocuments\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Test\Test\Program.cs:line 20
```

So its not throwing error immediately , but it throws error when try to access any member or method or any constructor of class.

That is what happen with RunTime also when it encounter scenario , in which entry point static constructor throws error. When CLR try to execute main method immediately it got exception which thrown by static constructor of program.

---

It is because `static void Main` is the entry point for the application. CLR finds this method (`static void Main`) first and then runs the rest of the things.

It might be the case here that this error is coming before executing main but CLR first goes to the entry point and then throws the exception. As there is no entry point for the application it might not throw exception immediately.

Comment: @Evk's answer would seem to suggest that this is not in fact the reason...

Comment: @Chris - than it should throw exception before reaching main , right ? but it is not the case , exception raised after reaching to entry point (I do know that as per microsoft static constructor get called first before any memeber or method of class get accessed but seems not case with OP code)

Comment: @PranayRana that's not the point, @Evk demonstrated that this can happen with static methods that are _not_ `Main`.

Comment: @PranayRana: IF you disagree with evk's analysis then you should comment on his answer to tell him why he is wrong. He seems to have demonstrated why the exception is being thrown when it is and I was just trying to draw your attention to that. I'm not saying that you are wrong, its just that you have two contradictory answers and his evidence seems pretty convincing.

Comment: @Chris - i am not saying he is wrong ...all i am saying is exception occurs when you try to access first first member or method of class , it will not come in first go...